# «Человек-пирожок» или «человек-пирожок»?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, кавычки

> Кирюша... А вот Кирюша — "Человек-пирожок"! Представьте бабулины
> румяные пирожки, которые только что из печки! Вот это и есть Кирюша.

1. Нужны ли кавычки?
2. "Ч" или "ч"?

Comment: Пирожок в смысле выпечка, или пирожок в смысле мемы про Буданова. Если мемы-то можно в кавычках с маленькой буквы. https://dzen.ru/a/ZIc8TYzeGhE37ML7

Comment: Живой человек выпечкой быть не может! Такого быть не должно!

Comment: Ну мне сложно понять, вы в прямом значении пишите, или это опять игра слов или метафора. Я так понял, что Кирюша - это Кирилл Буданов, которого называют почему-то "мамин пирожок", или я не понял о чем вы пишите в принципе. И Человек-пирожок - если это название выпечки, это уже Имя, зачем тут еще Кирюша? То есть зачем Человеку-пирожку два имени? Не понятно. Мальчик-с-пальчик - его так и звали, а не Кирюша. Хотя может это какой-то пост модерн, но опять же постмодерн он на референсах, например - Буданов.

Comment: Я не знаю, кто такой Буданов... Ничего не поняла! Я простой человек! Кирюша  — это упитанный румяный мальчик из соседского дома!

Comment: Кирюша - это мальчик и вы хотите сказать что он пирожок? зачем тогда человек? Кирюша-пирожок.

Comment: Здесь ирония! Маленький мальчик сидит на коленях у пожилой женщины, соседки. Она теребит его румяные щёчки и говорит разные милые глупости! Там разговор шёл сначала о том, что её родной внук в детстве играл в Человека-паука.

Comment: Вооот, и я об этом, видите, тут мультикультурный микс. Потому что у нас в сказках никогда не было человечков-пирожков, или человечков-пауков, был только "мужичок с ноготок" - но не человечек. Потому что man - это муж, мужик, мужичок - указание на пол/род скорее, а не "человек" от слова совсем. Спайдер-мэн - это Паук-мужик, а не Человек-паук, как у нас переводят, то есть просто паук, а не паучиха, это именно кривые переводы с инглиша. Вот. А из этого уже заведомо кривого перевода, женщина создает новую тоже химерную сущность(в русском языке) - человека-пирожка. Кирюша - Человек-пирожок.

Comment: Причем, заметьте, в инглише это был Спайдер-мэн, мэн это было как бы частицей к Спайдер, Спайдер, потому что они вынуждены писать такие вещи с большой буквы, такой язык, потому что спайдер это по-русски скорее "паучье", чем паук или паучиха, просто указание на класс животного. А в русском получается слово урод Человек-паук, паук - придаточная часть или частица, не знаю точно как это назвать, а акцент на человека, причем тут человек? Уберем определение: Кирюша - не паук, верно, Кирюша -мальчик, но также Кирюша - не Человек, - критическая ошибка). Или теперь придется говорить Человек-мальчик?

Comment: Да, к Паук-мужик. Есть же Cat-woman, по-русски Кошка, без всяких там женщина, потому что кошка - это уже кошачье женского пола, а Кошка - уже явно чьё-то именование-кличка. А вот Женщина-кошка - меняет и акценты и вообще создает, чёрт знает, какие ассоциации. Я -Бэтмэн - Человек-летучая-мышь - мрачный крепыш... Как-то так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы написал **А вот Кирюша - человек-пирожок**.

Просто подлежащее (*Кирюша*) и сказуемоё (*человек*) + приложение (*пирожок*), и всё. Да и вообще, я бы не выделял *пирожок* как приложение, а считал бы всё словосочетание *человек-пирожок* единым сказуемым.

Прописную, то есть большую Ч, можно оставить, только если *Человек-пирожок* мыслится как имя собственное, как уникальное прозвище. Это мыслится автором?

Что до кавычек, их можно поставить, если слову придаётся какое-нибудь условное или ироническе значение либо двойной смысл. Вкладывает ли автор в *человек-пирожок* такой смысл - это неясный пока вопрос.

Comment: Здесь ирония! Маленький мальчик сидит на коленях у пожилой женщины, соседки. Она теребит его румяные щёчки и говорит разные милые глупости! Там разговор шёл сначала о том, что её родной внук в детстве играл в Человека-паука.